# I want to close the jQuery window on click of a close button

Tags: jquery, asp.net, c#-4.0

My jQuery code is this

```
   $("#close").click(function () {

    });
  $(document).keyup(function(e) {
      if (e.keyCode == 27) {  }   // esc
  });
```

I want to close my image view window and back to my previous page, how can I do this?

Comment: NONONONONO! it's jQuery, not Jquery.  __tears__

Comment: How did you create the image view window? Is it a new window created from the parent window using window.open ?

Comment: @SnakesandCoffee you can always edit a question and correct it...

Comment: `JQuery window` dont get it.

Comment: Whizkid747 i crated using jquery as we see on facebook when we click on any pic we see d enlarge image nd den if der is close button i want to return back to my previous window

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
$("#yourDivWithImage").hide();
```

Comment: `.hide();` `<------------see the lowercase-----<<< :)`

Answer (score 0):

If it's in a new window then: http://jsfiddle.net/pBALx/

```
var w = window.open("urlToImagePage");

$("#close").click(function () {
    w.close();
});
$(document).keyup(function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 27){
        w.close();
    }
});
```

Comment: it is not an new window it is an new dialog open by parent window

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I totally understand what you want to do but, if you want to close a window/dialog on escape keypressed and run what is in your #close.Click function, well you could simply trigger your event like this :

```
$("#close").click(function () {

//some code to be executed

});

$(document).keyup(function(e) {

if (e.keyCode == 27) {  }   // esc
  $("#close").triggerHanlder("click");
});
```

But thats somehow a dirty way to do it...

Answer (score 0):

**Thanks alot guys for your answers i had done wid my answer by providing an link of dat previous page on click of dat close div so it will go back to dat page still it is waste of memory as the parent page is loading again but it works .... 
thanks**